# Why is the double negation of the axiom of choice rarely considered?

Tags: topos-theory, axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics

In constructive/intuitionistic mathematics, it is common to reject the axiom of choice, because it is highly nonconstructive and implies the law of the excluded middle by Diaconescu's theorem/Bishop's freshman exercise.

However, what about the *double negation* of the axiom of choice? I.e. the statement that any surjective function does *not not* have a section. Or more generally, use of the axiom of choice could be governed by a Tierney operator that does not have to be double negation.

Comment: What about the triple negation?

Comment: @VilleSalo Triple negation is still the same as single negation intuitionistically. More generally, (((P -> Q) -> Q) -> Q) implies P -> Q in any logic where implication is remotely well-defined, by since you can compose it with modus ponens P -> ((P->Q) -> Q) . Triple negation elimination is the special case where Q is False.

Comment: Do you have an example of something you can prove using this?

Comment: I think one reason is that even that weaker principle is outright false in many of the constructive semantics people care about (e.g. many toposes). Do you know of an interesting model of constructive logic in which the double negation of AC holds?

Comment: @JoshuaZ One first example would be the double negation of practically anything you would have in ZFC-like foundations, using Gödel-Gentzen translation:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-negation_translation

Comment: @NoahSchweber Right. I don't have a good intuition for cases where it is true where AC does not hold, though I would expect double negation of choice but not choice itself to be true in many settings where failure of LEM represents undecidability/uncomputability.

Comment: Actually, come to think of it, a good first sanity check could be to see if double negation of choice implies De Morgan's laws. In that case I think it would imply that a topos satisfying that would have to be extremally disconnected if viewed as a space.

Comment: I think the Sierpiński topos should be an example?

Comment: It looks like double negation of choice for a localic topos is related to the locale being hyperconnected (since choice has to be true on a dense open subset).  The easiest way I can think of for that to be true is for the space to be hyperconnected with an open point. The axiom of choice will clearly hold at any open point, and so if the open point is dense it will hold for the topos.